# Clearing macros

Tags: stata

The following command removes all variables, scalars and programs that I add:

```
clear all
```

However, global and local macros stick around.

I would like to know how to clear these out:

- interactively from the command line and/or
- as an opening line in my `do` files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can drop all macros with:

```
macro drop _all
```

This is documented in `help macro` and the corresponding manual entry.

Answer (score 3):

The command below also removes some of my other global macros, which I do not want to remove:

```
macro drop _all
```

I prefer the following command, which tells you all the macros you have defined:

```
macro list _all
```

For example, `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `y1`, `y2`, `y3`, `z1`, `z2` and so on.

If you then just want to drop only macros `y` and `z` (but not `x`), then you can use this command:

```
capture macro drop y1 y2 y3 z1 z2
```

or

```
capture macro drop y* z*
```